# How to play two remote streams simultaneously

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming

How do I simultaneously play two remote streams (https://...m3u8), one video and one audio, from the command line? **Important note:** I need to set several HTTP headers for the streams to work.

I'm on macOS, and I have VLC, FFmpeg and streamlink installed. FFplay supports setting HTTP headers, but does not support playing more than one stream, so that one's out of the picture.

**Update**: I now have a working solution for FFmpeg/FFplay, but I'm leaving the question open for a working solution with VLC or streamlink (that allows for better jumping in the stream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ffmpeg together with ffplay

```
ffmpeg -headers X -i .. -headers Y -i .. -c copy -f nut - | ffplay -f nut -i -
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Worked straight away. The streaming was a bit jerky, though that's probably a performance or bandwidth issue. One question: Do I need to specify `-headers` before every `-i`?

Comment: Yes, it applies per-input.

Comment: I also noticed that using `-f mp4` and `-f matroska` doesn't work (`The muxer does not support seeking`). Is there a container that will let me save the file to disk while streaming? `ffmpeg ... -f ??? - | tee out | ffplay ...`

Comment: `ffmpeg -headers X -i .. -headers Y -i .. -c copy file.mp4 -c copy -f nut - | ffplay -f nut -i -`

Comment: I noticed something else: Normally, using the cursor keys, FFplay can jump 10 seconds (left/right) and 1 minute (up/down) in a streamed video. However, when streaming from two sources, the player instead jumps nothing(?) and maybe 2-3 seconds, respectively, while the program output says `no syncpoint at backptr pos`. Can this be remedied in any way?

Comment: The first process is receiving the data but the seek is being processed by the next one (ffplay) so that will only work within its cached buffer.